# Unable to set pricebook Id in orderitems

Tags: apex, trigger, pricebook, after-trigger, pricebookentry

I am writing trigger "On Insert Of Order(Sales order) copy opportunityLineitems to order line items" I have done everything fine upto my knowledge but when I am inserting order it is showing pricebook not set error.

Thanks In Advance

Trigger Code:-

```
trigger orderLineCreationSherry on order(after insert)
{
    set<string> strSet = new set<string>();
    list<order> orList = new list<order>();
    list<OrderItem> oliPist=new list<OrderItem>();
    list<opportunity> oppList=new list<opportunity>();

    for(order o:trigger.new){
        strSet.add(o.OpportunityId);
    }
    system.debug('strSet========'+strSet);

    map<string,opportunity> mapOpp = new map<string,opportunity>([SELECT id,Name, (SELECT id,name,Product2Id,Quantity FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE id in:strSet]);
    system.debug('oppList========='+oppList);

    for(order o:trigger.new)
    {
        List<Order> oderLst = new List<Order>();
        Opportunity opp = mapOpp.get(o.OpportunityId);
        if(opp.OpportunityLineItems.size()!=0){
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli : opp.OpportunityLineItems)
            {   
                PriceBook2 pb2Standard =[select Id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];
                Id standardPriceBookId = pb2Standard.Id;
                system.debug('standardPriceBookId===========>>>>>>>>>>>>'+standardPriceBookId);
                Id currentProductId=oli.Product2Id;
                system.debug('currentProductId===========>>>>>>'+currentProductId);
                PricebookEntry pbe = [SELECT Id,Product2Id,Pricebook2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id =:standardPriceBookId AND Product2Id =:currentProductId AND isActive = true LIMIT 1];
                system.debug('Here Is Pricebook2 ID'+pbe.id);
                system.debug('INsideloop');
                OrderItem od = new OrderItem();
                od.OrderId=o.Id;
                od.Quantity=oli.Quantity;
                od.PricebookEntryId=pbe.Id;
                od.Product2Id=oli.Product2Id;
                oliPist.add(od);
            }
        system.debug('Here Is Field Data=========>>>>>>'+oliPist);
      }  
        system.debug('Its Reaching Here');
    }
    if(oliPist.size()!=0){
        system.debug('It Will Be Debuged Now INsert Zone');
        insert oliPist;
    }
}
```

Comment: This Error I am Facing
Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger orderLineCreationSherry caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: orderLineCreationSherry: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Price Book Not Set on Sales Order: []: Trigger.orderLineCreationSherry: line 44, column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two triggers one before insert and one after insert on order.

```
trigger OrderTriggerBefore on Order (before insert) {

set<Id> OpportunityId = new set<Id>();
for(Order ord :trigger.new) {
    if(ord.OpportunityId != null) {
        OpportunityId.add(ord.OpportunityId);
    }
}
Map<Id,Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([select Id,pricebook2Id from Opportunity where Id In :OpportunityId]);
for(Order ord :trigger.new) {
    ord.Pricebook2Id = oppMap.get(ord.OpportunityId).pricebook2Id;
}}`
```

after this do create this

```
trigger OrderTrigger on Order (After insert) {
set<Id> oppId = new Set<Id>();
set<Id> pcrId = new set<Id>(); 
List<OrderItem> oliPist = new  List<OrderItem>();
for(Order ord : trigger.new) {
    if(ord.opportunityId != null) {
        oppId.add(ord.opportunityId);
    }
}

Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>> olitoOpp = new  Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>>();

for(OpportunityLineItem oli : [select Id,Quantity,UnitPrice,PricebookEntryId,Product2Id,OpportunityId from OpportunityLineItem where opportunityId In : oppId ]) {
    pcrId.add(oli.Product2Id);
    if(olitoOpp.containsKey(oli.opportunityId)) {
        olitoOpp.get(oli.opportunityId).add(oli);
    }
    else {
        olitoOpp.put(oli.opportunityId, new List<OpportunityLineItem>{oli});
    }
}
For(Order ord : trigger.new) {
    if(olitoOpp.containsKey(ord.opportunityId)) {
        for(OpportunityLineItem  oli : olitoOpp.get(ord.opportunityId)){

            OrderItem od = new OrderItem();
            od.OrderId=ord.Id;
            od.Quantity=oli.Quantity;
            od.PricebookEntryId=oli.PricebookEntryId;
            od.UnitPrice = oli.UnitPrice;
            od.Product2Id=oli.Product2Id;
            oliPist.add(od);
        }
    }

}

if(!oliPist.isEmpty()) {
    insert oliPist;
}
```

}